# Thymeleaf: Using literals in fragment's parameter

Tags: spring, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In template `header` I have

```
<head th:fragment="common_header(title)">
  <title th:replace="${title}">Default title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ...
</head>
```

I tried using literals in parameter:

```
<head th:replace="~{header::common_header(title='This should be real title')}">
  <title>Just for template's sake...</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ...
</head>
```

but all I'm getting is

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "This should be real title", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "header" - line 4, col 9)`

What am I doing wrong? Using `_` (no-operation token) yields with `Default title` (as expected)

Comment: Do you have your `header` template in the `/template` folder? And what is at line 4 of your `header` file?

Comment: @BennettDams yes, I have. And 4th line is `<title th:replace="${title}">Default title</title>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `th:replace` expects a template expression, and not a text variable.  Does it work if you change it to:

```
<title th:text="${title}">Default title</title>
```